# How Can i replicate Photoshop like functionality to save and restore UI Layouts?

Tags: android, user-interface

I built an android application in which user can add views like edit text, text views & image views to Relative layout and export the  layout as image . But most of my users requesting feature to save their work as template to work on it later point just as like .PSD file in Photoshop. I am unable to find a Way to achieve this. How can I save Views and its properties inside a layout to inflate them later at any point of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way. Although I haven't written the relevant code, I think it is feasible.
You can create a class, this class has the following properties:

- View type
- View level
- View's superView
- View's subViews
- Size
- Layouts
- etc.(*you can add it according to your needs.*)

Then convert each View into this class, save all the converted classes to the local, when the next time you need to use, you can read all the classes saved locally last time, and according to the class attributes, such as view type, view level, size, layouts and other attributes create all views in turn.

Comment: OK. Thanks For response. I will try and Update